# Is there a way to execute an arp spoof on Windows?

Tags: arp, spoofing

You can easily set up arp spoofs on linux using the arpspoof command in terminal.

My question is - is there a piece of software that would allow you to do the same on Windows?

So far I've seen Nighthawk, but I can not find any information about it; such as a review to verify it's integrity.

Thanks!

(My intentions are for educational purposes only)

Comment: Ive used Nighthawk before, in its simplified mode it simply spoofs the Gateway address to all other hosts and in the process captures data from cookies,ssl stripping,hhtp auth etc. Fairly simple to use. Hope u have the link : https://code.google.com/p/nighthawk/downloads/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cain & Abel would do this for you.

Link: http://www.oxid.it/cain.html

There a various guides if you search google so I won't reference them here. I've used this tool for a long time, not for ARP spoofing but as a network monitoring tool and to track down culprits in a slow network.

Comment: I can confirm that it works, I tried out the arp spoofing a few years ago to learn about it. But I do think it requires special drivers (pcap) to be installed in order to be able do it (they are included, but will require a administrator's privileges to install). Also it was designed for Windows XP, I don't know if it will work for Vista or newer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer! Also @ScottChamberlain It works in all versions of Windows as far as I know. It's working in Windows 8 for me, you just need to turn off the pesky anti virus or it doesn't boot properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend a tool called WinARPspoof. It is very reliable and works well.

The site is actually down, because it is actually really old. You can get it from archive.org:

https://web.archive.org/web/20050907005625/http://www.nextsecurity.net/

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of the tool you suggest in operation?